# Does excel retain RLS when a saved copy of `analyze in excel` report is shared with another user?

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel#save-and-share-your-new-workbook

> When a user opens the workbook that you’ve shared your workbook with
> them, they see your PivotTables and data as they were when you last
> saved the workbook.

Does RLS not apply when an excel file is shared with another user?

For exmaple: suppose I have RLS to restrict myself only to see country A. But if person having access to country B opens the analyze in excel report and saves this and shares it to me, then will I see country B even though I don't have access to country B?

Ofcourse if I refresh it will only show me country A based on my RLS.

Answer (score 2):

You share a current snapshot of excel so yes, you can see Country B, because there is no way to validated RLS rules without refreshing (without sending a request to the powerbi Engine);  Think about this as saving screenshot and sharing this screenshot.

Comment: But it should make the check when opening the file to ensure RLS is applied. This is otherwise a security risk wherein a user (one who shares) might assume RLS is applicable upon first time open as well.

Comment: msta42a's answer is correct regardless of how you think it should work though.

Comment: Also Analyze in Excel is really just Excel connected to Analysis Services and it has worked like this for a very long time.

Comment: `Row-level security (RLS) is supported for Analyze in Excel. RLS is enforced at the data-model level, and is always applied to all users accessing data in the report.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel#considerations-and-limitations. Why does it say RLS is always applied to all all users accessing the report (they should mention in the doc about the shared file scenario risk)?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend if the data visible in the Analyze in Excel PivotTable is sensitive you should not share this without first [Clearing the PivotTable Cache](https://olappivottableextensions.github.io/Clear-PivotTable-Cache.html). This is a feature of the free OLAP PivotTable Extensions add-in for Excel.

It is true that upon refresh (with or without first clearing the PivotTable cache) that the user will have to authenticate with Power BI and RLS should properly limit the data visible in the PivotTable after refresh. The question is the initial data visible in the sheet which a user can see without authenticating to Power BI.